# Proof that $P(\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n) = 0$ - isn't it equal to $P(A_n)$?

Tags: probability, limits, probability-limit-theorems

For the question to be more understandable, here is a link for a screenshot:

[image: the exercise]

Using the definition from below the to be proven statement, I have come to the following conclusion:

$\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n = \cap_{n\ge 1} (\cup_{k\ge n} A_k) = (A_1 \cup ... \cup A_n) \cap (A_2 \cup ... \cup A_n) \cap ... \cap (A_n \cup A_n) = A_n$ therefore $P(\limsup_{n\to \infty} A_n) = 0$ only if $P(A_n) = 0$.

Is that correct or have I made some logical error here, it doesn't say anywhere in the exercise that $P(A_n) = 0$.

I'd be very glad if one of you could help me with this and also send me some formatting cheat sheet for this website so the questions can get easier to read.

Comment: We can have $P(A_n)=\frac  1{2^{n}}$, for example.

Comment: It is not "only if $P(A_n)=0$" as there will be examples where the sum of terms is bounded even if each one is positive.  This is the Borel–Cantelli lemma - see [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) or [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel-Cantelli-Lemma)

Comment: Here is a tutorial for the formatting https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, and also in German!
https://www.mathelounge.de/509545/mathjax-latex-basic-tutorial-und-referenz-deutsch

Comment: Hint: this is known as the Borel Cantelli Lemma. It follows from the continuity of measure (measure of infinite intersection equals limit of …)

Comment: It seems that you are misinterpreting the inner union. $\cup A_k$ for ${k\geq n}$ is $A_n\cup A_{n+1}\cup A_{n+2}\cup\dots$ up to infinity. Then you intersect all such unions, i.e. you find only the points that lie in "the tail of the sequence $\lbrace A_n\rbrace_n$.

Comment: okay, I have understood the issue, thank you all for your replies!